# Armadillo-IoT G3をgcc7へアップグレードする方法

Tags: linux, debian

お世話になります。
Armadillo-IoT G3(Linux9(stretch))をgcc7へアップグレードしたいのですが、Debianの公式サイトで公開されているdebファイルをdpkgコマンドで手動で行ったところ、設定中の表示が出てそのまま終わってしまい、またaptitudeコマンドで自動で行おうとしたものの今度はgcc-7が見つからないと言われました。

Armadillo-IoT G3でgcc7へアップグレードされた方いましたらご教示ください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://users.atmark-techno.com/forum/armadillo/3982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stretchは現在 **安定版 (stable)** ですが、gcc-7は **buster (testing)** か **sid (unstable)** 以降で提供されているようです。

[Debian パッケージ検索結果 -- gcc-7](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gcc-7)

そのままではstableにインストール出来ないので、testing/unstableのミラーサーバをsources.listに追加し、指定パッケージの優先度を設定することで該当のパッケージのみを借りてくることができるようです。

参考:
[Debian: 任意のtesting/unstableパッケージのみをinstallする方法 (システム全体はstableを維持)](https://debimate.jp/2019/03/09/debian-%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AEtesting-unstable%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%82%92install%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86/)

Comment: 詳細に教えて頂きありがとうございます。無事gcc-7が見つかりインストール開始するところまでは進めました。ただ依存関係で先にインストールしなければならないパッケージが出てきましてので、先にそちらから解決していきます。